# Why does my jQuery plugin show up as text in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript

I am attempting to install [unslider](http://unslider.com/) jquery plugin for my WordPress website. I enter the below code inside my WordPress text editor and I don't get the expected result. I changed $ to jQuery and that didn't fix it either.

```
<!-- The barebones HTML required for Unslider -->
<div class="banner">
    <ul><li>This is my slider.</li><li>Pretty cool, huh?</li></ul>
</div>

<!-- And the relevant JavaScript -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/unslider.js"></script> <!-- but with the right path! -
->
<script>$(function() { $('.banner').unslider() })</script>
```

Output:

This is my slider.
Pretty cool, huh?

$(function() { $(‘.banner’).unslider() })

Comment: You have a broken end of comment `->` with a `\n` in between `-` and the `->`, move it up to the end of `<-- but with the right path! -->`.

Comment: We don't know if it's pretty cool, it's not working

Comment: You can't and shouldn't put arbitrary HTMLin the post/page editor, it gets stripped out by the security filters. There are ways of removing those, but it will make your site much easier to hack. If you need to put scripts and embed codes in the middle of content then use a shortcode

Comment: @TomJNowell Where can I put this code? functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this PHP code to output your slider's initiator in your themes footer:

```
add_action('wp_footer','initiate_unslider');
function initiate_unslider () {
    ?>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/path/to/unslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('.banner').unslider();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Also it's safer to add a `$(document).ready` before initiating your slider, in case some necessary components of your page has not been loaded yet.

Comment: This breaks my site when added to footer.php or functions.php. Where did you want me to add this?

Comment: In your `functions.php` file. Did you open and close the php tags properly? I added the opening and closing tags to the code. BTW, what kind of break? Fatal php error?

Comment: I didn't open and close the php tags properly. I got a Server 500 error

Comment: Sorry my bad. I forgot to use the word `function`. It should work now.

Comment: I got another serve 500 error. Trying your updated code!

Comment: I tested this code right now, and it worked. Put it at the end of your theme's `functions.php` file, and be careful about PHP tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57231/discussion-between-brody-james-and-jack-johansson).